# Haskell selective import only working partially

Tags: haskell, import

Apparently, this selective import only works partially:

```
λ> :m
λ> import Data.Monoid (Sum, getSum)
λ> :t getSum
getSum :: Sum a -> a
λ> :t Sum

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Data constructor not in scope: Sum
    • Perhaps you meant variable ‘sum’ (imported from Prelude)
```

But a complete import does work:

```
λ> import Data.Monoid
λ> :t Sum
Sum :: a -> Sum a
```

Why can I import getSum but not Sum from Monoid?

I'm using GHCi 8.0.2 installed with Stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import the constructor for `Sum`:

```hs
λ> import Data.Monoid (Sum(..), getSum)
```

This will import all the constructors (in the case of an *enum/sum type*), if you want to only import one constructor, you can do it like this:

```hs
λ> import Data.Monoid (Sum(Sum), getSum)
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, this bit of information is not present on the Haskell Wiki and the other sources I looked at.

Comment: Also, just in case it throws anyone, let me add a disambiguation of some coincidentally-overlapping terminology: a *sum type* is one with multiple constructors, like `data Either a b = Left a | Right b`.  As it happens, the type `Sum` is *not* a sum type!  (It's `newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }`.)

Comment: @Tobia If you want the gory details: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1010005.3

Comment: Antal Spector-Zabusky thanks for the disambiguation, in hindsight I should have probably seen that. I'll change it to *enum/sum type*.